# Optimal way to cache time of day description

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, time

What is the best method to cache the following? I am creating an intranet web application template that will display the message, e.g., **Good Morning, Justin Satyr!** near the top of my master page header. Obviously, I will have to determine whether to show **Morning**, **Afternoon** or **Evening**. For clarity, my code is below:

```
string partOfDay;
var hours = DateTime.Now.Hour;
if (hours > 16)
{
    partOfDay = "evening";
}
else if (hours > 11)
{
    partOfDay = "afternoon";
}
else
{
    partOfDay = "morning";
}
```

I do not want to re-determine this on each page load because that seems moderately redundant and because I have to poll a SQL server to retrieve the user's full name. What is the best way to cache this information?  If I cache it for the length of the session, then if the user begins using the application at 11:00 AM and finishes at 3:00 PM, it will still say **Good Morning**.

Is the best thing to do simply re-determine the M/A/E word each page load and cache the person's full name for the session? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Emh..why don't you keep the user name in the Session object? For the rest you don't really need any caching.

Comment: That is what I was asking in the second to last sentence, but I thought perhaps there is a way to force that information to expire at a specific time. If so, then I could cache it in the application, although that would cause problems for users in different time zones...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would just keep the user name in the Session object, the rest honestly is not worth caching and checking if it is out of date etc., just re-run it on each page - provided you put the implementation into a common library /class so you keep your code DRY.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion there is absolutely no need to cache the part of day. User information can be made available in the Session.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking in ASP.NET MVC context, you can use **System.Web.Helpers** namespace, where you can find WebCache helper. Than you need to calculate minutes to time of day_time will be changed and call **WebCache.Set** method with paramters: value="your string", minutesToCache=calculated_value.

Answer (score 0):

Old, I know, but I don't cache mine, due to the obvious reason that the users time may change during the session. I store their calculated time in my session (calculates based on their timezone), and then use this code at the top of all pages:

```
<strong>@string.Format("Good {0}, ", SessionManager.GetUserCurrentDate().Hour > 16 ? "Evening" : SessionManager.GetUserCurrentDate().Hour > 11 ? "Afternoon" : "Morning") + SessionManager.GetDisplayName())</strong>
```

Works well for me!